# Generate text using user-supplied keywords

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, language-model, text-generation, gpt

I've got a use case where I need to generate sentences based on a set of user supplied keywords. Here is an example of what I need:

### User input:

**End-User:** Data Scientists

**Region:** Middle East

**Country:** UAE

**Solution:** BigPanda

**Application:** machine learning

**Benefits:** lower costs and runtime

### ***Output (Curly-Brackets are just there to highlight):***

Learn how {data scientists} in the {Middle East} such as in the {UAE} are using {BigPanda} to streamline their {machine learning} processes to {lower costs and runtime}.

---

So the model needs to use the keywords given by the user and generate similar sentences. I also have a dataset of about 2000 of such sentences, which may come in handy.

One way I thought this could be possible is by using the GPT-2 model and perhaps finetuning it with the dataset, but I haven't been able to figure out how I would actually go about using it for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes fine-tuning GPT2 could help you through this objective. But the only concern is regarding the size of input data you have. To get a better performing model, you must a have larger input set.